# SPD 2013 workflow using REST API to create site with unique permissions (UseUniquePermissions)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

In a SPD 2013 workflow, how is the 'UseUniquePermissions' parameter configured when it's set to 'true' in order to create unique permissions for a site? how do you declare and grant user(s) to have a specific permission?

I can't find any documentation/examples for configuring that parameter to set unique permissions (UseUniquePermissions). All examples show the parameter set to false for inheriting permissions.

[image]

Anybody here have tips?

Comment: Are you coding a solution with the REST Api's in any particular language? Server-side? Client-side?

Comment: To grant unique permissions the way is set BreakRoleInheritance property and set roles. See an example how it is doing programmatically http://projectservercode.com/programmatically-breaking-inheritance-and-add-unique-permission/

Comment: I need to do this with a SharePoint Designer based workflow

Answer (score 0):

In the SPWeb object, you have a HasUniqueRoleAssignments property to check the web has unique permissions. You can not set this property.

Here are the steps

1. Create site.
2. Break the permissions using a second rest call

   `newsiteurl/_api/web/breakroleinheritance(true)`
3. Add new role assignments using below example rest api call

   `newsiteurl/_api/web/web/roleassignments`

Go through the following articles to get full details on this calls.

[How to break permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebBreakRoleInheritance)

[How to grant permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_RoleAssignment)

Make sure in the workflow you should use the `Call HTTP Web Service` action.

Comment: Is this used in conjunction with the "UseUniquePermissions" parameter set to true?

Comment: No. With out that parameter create a  site.

Answer (score 0):

I assume OP has solved his question, but for future reference. If creatng a site with the parameter `UseUniquePermissions = true` then a call to the andpoint grants permission to the user/group:

```
_api/web/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[principal id of group/user],roleDefId=[Role defination id of the permission level])
```

Notice the two placeholders en brackets